# cy,click() is not clicking the entity i want to click instead click some other entity in cypress

Tags: javascript, automation, automated-tests, cypress

There is a text field in which I enter random data  and save the form, now I want to click the edit button on the basis of that value which consists of a random value

how I enter a random value in the text field and save it in a variable.

```
function Alpha_Numeric() {
        
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
   }
```

Calling variable

```
cy.contains('td',text).get('#work_order_edit').click()
```

Instead of click the specific element the pointer click on random vale in the table[image: random value text in table]

[image: pointer clicking]

Comment: Can yo add the html for one of the row, showing all elements?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving from the cell to the row, then finding the edit button

```js
cy.contains('td',text)
  .parent('tr')
  .find('#work_order_edit')
  .click()
```